# Unable to delete a document within an Index using Java RestHigh Level Client (Delete By Query)

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am using Elasticsearch 7.10 and want to delete a document inside an index using Delete By Query. I have referenced the official documentation on how to use the library but not sure what exactly i am missing. Any help is appreciated.

```
    String indexName = "test_delete_index";

    Map<String, String> testDoc = new HashMap<>();
    testDoc.put("user", "abc");
    testDoc.put("postDate", new Date().toString());
    testDoc.put("message", "Test the Delete Method with Version");
    testDoc.put("gender", "male");

    DeleteByQueryRequest request = new DeleteByQueryRequest(indexName);
    request.setConflicts("proceed");
    request.setRefresh(true);
    request.setQuery(new TermQueryBuilder ("gender","male"));

    BulkByScrollResponse deleteResponse = client.deleteByQuery(request,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println("Delete By Query ::: " + deleteResponse.getDeleted());
```

The output says nothing got deleted :

Delete By Query ::: 0

Answer (score 0):

I first indexed the doc "testDoc" and deleteByquery worked.

```
String indexName = "test_delete_index";

    Map<String, String> testDoc = new HashMap<>();
    testDoc.put("user", "abc");
    testDoc.put("postDate", new Date().toString());
    testDoc.put("message", "Test the Delete Method with Version");
    testDoc.put("gender", "male");

    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName);
    indexRequest.source(testDoc);

    IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println("Insert Doc ::: " + response.toString());

    DeleteByQueryRequest request = new DeleteByQueryRequest(indexName);
    request.setConflicts("proceed");
    request.setRefresh(true);
    request.setQuery(new TermQueryBuilder("gender", "male"));

    BulkByScrollResponse deleteResponse = client.deleteByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println("Delete By Query ::: " + deleteResponse.getDeleted());
```

Comment: I still see the document is not deleted. Delete By Query ::: 0. I forgot to mention that i have created the index after setting the map values.

Comment: Try "gender.keyword". Maybe it could be something with your mapping, if you can share it too.

Comment: It doesn't work with "gender.keyword".  Mapping is very simple:  
{
  "properties": {
    "index_name": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "store": "false",
      "index": "true"
    },
    "gender": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "store": "true",
      "index": "true"
    }
  }
}

Comment: If you run the example I posted it still doesn't delete?

Comment: No, I still see the deleted count as 0. What is the mapping document are you using. I can try with that.